# SynEdit создание собственной подсветки

Tags: delphi, pascal

Всем привет. Давно уже на Delphi ничего не писал, и решил немного размяться ... И самое первое, что пришло в голову - написать текстовый редактор. Но я решил немного усложнить себе цель, добавить подсветку родного паскаля в этот редактор. На помощь пришли SynEdit (SynMemo) и SynPasSyn. Ну и чтобы получше разобраться с SynEdit решил покапаться в демках, а именно HighlighterDemo.

В этом демо представлен компонент (TSynCustomHighlighter) с собственной подсветкой слов `hello`, `synEdit` и `world`:

```
  TSynSampleSyn = class(TSynCustomHighlighter)
  private
    fRange: TRangeState;
    fTokenID: TtkTokenKind;
    fIdentFuncTable: array[0..3] of TIdentFuncTableFunc;

...

  KeyWords: array[0..3] of UnicodeString = (
    'hello', 'synedit', 'world', 'highlighter'
  );

  KeyIndices: array[0..3] of Integer = (
    0, 2, 1, 3
  );

procedure TSynSampleSyn.InitIdent;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(fIdentFuncTable) to High(fIdentFuncTable) do
    if KeyIndices[i] = -1 then
      fIdentFuncTable[i] := AltFunc;

  fIdentFuncTable[0] := FuncHello;
  fIdentFuncTable[2] := FuncWorld;
  fIdentFuncTable[1] := FuncSynedit;
  fIdentFuncTable[3] := FuncHightLight;

...

function TSynSampleSyn.FuncHightLight(Index: Integer): TtkTokenKind;
begin
  if IsCurrentToken(KeyWords[Index]) then
    Result := tkKey
  else
    Result := tkIdentifier;
end;
```

Но вот заставить, чтобы подсвечивалось ещё и `highlighter`, никак не выходит ...

**UPDATE** Обновил индексы, но всё равно `highlighter` не подсвечивается

Comment: А зачем вы присвоили одинаковые индексы для `hello` и `highlighter`? По-моему, именно тут и проблема. Дайте новому ключевому слову новый индекс.

Comment: Исправил индексы, но результата никакого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если внимательно почитать комментарии в `SynHighlighterSample.pas`, то можно увидеть вот такие строки:

```
Code template generated with SynGen.
The original code is: D:\Quellen\Komponenten\SynEdit\Demos\HighlighterDemo\SynHighlighterSample.pas, released 2008-10-25.
Description: 
The initial author of this file is Maël Hörz.
Copyright (c) 2008, all rights reserved.
```

Из чего можно сделать вывод, что для создания подсветок в `SynEdit` используется кодогенерация, а утилита для генерирования кода называется `SynGen`. Утилита эта поставляется вместе с `SynEdit` и имеет свою справку (`SynGen\Highlighters-HowTo.html`).

Если в двух словах, то вам надо написать/отредактировать шаблон для вашей подсветки (файл с расширением `.msg`), открыть этот шаблон в `SynGen` и сгенерировать исходник. В демке есть шаблон `SynHighlighterSample.msg` и чтобы заставить хайлайтер подсвечивать слово `highlighter`, достаточно вписать его в секцию `KEYS`:

```
KEYS
Hello
World
Highlighter
|><|
```

Изменить же вручную сорцы готового хайлайтера (в плане добавления новых ключевых слов) не получится из-за функции `TSynSampleSyn.HashKey`. Эта функция считает хэш слов, который используется затем для вызова соответствующей функции из `fIdentFuncTable`.

В общем виде, функция `HashKey` выглядит так:

```
{$Q-}
function TSynSampleSyn.HashKey(Str: PWideChar): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := 0;
  while IsIdentChar(Str^) do
  begin
    Result := Result * c + Ord(Str^) * d;
    inc(Str);
  end;
  Result := Result mod m;
  fStringLen := Str - fToIdent;
end;
{$Q+}
```

И задача кодогенератора вычислить коэффициенты `c`, `d` и `m`, в зависимости от ключевых слов (алгоритм генератора можно посмотреть в `SynGen\HashTableGen.pas`).

Comment: Спасибо. Всю прошлую ночь разбирался с этой демкой(HighlighterDemo). Понял, как работает эта подсветка, но я вручную правил KeyIndices и HashKey, но разобраться зачем нужен SynHighlighterSample.msg я так и не смог. Но теперь всё ясно. Ещё раз спасибо Вам! +1 к вашему сообщению ))